# Is it possible to send data from java class file to node.js to display

Tags: java, node.js, express

I am fetching data from mongodb through java class file (IDE: eclipse) and I have web page designed using Node.js and express. Is it possible to send the output of java into nodejs to display on web browser?

Answer (score 1):

Of course it is.

Your IDE has absolutely nothing to do with it.

node.js uses HTTP/HTTPS to communicate with clients.  It can create an HTTP/HTTPS request to get information from a listener that happens to be written in Java to get information.

If that Java listener happens to format the response in terms of JSON it's easy for node.js and web clients to consume it.